# Yii Register core script is calling controller name

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, yii, tinymce

I recently turned on the path version of UrlManager for Yii. I'm running TinyMCE and this has predictably broken. I can see the problem, but don't know exactly how to fix. It's calling the script with the controller-

```
http://localhost:8888/content_management/content/assets/js/jquery.js
```

The controller is called content, the script is contained within the assets folder in the root directory.

The correct path for the script is-

```
http://localhost:8888/content_management/assets/js/jquery.js
```

Does anyone know how to stop Yii from calling the script via the controller id? Sorry if this is an obvious thing, I'm still fairly new to Yii.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

I probably should have added this. Here's how I'm calling the scripts-

```
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/assets/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

Is there something obviously wrong with these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a UrlManager  issue?
It could be a case of not using the base URL function:

```
Yii::app()->request->baseUrl
```

This points to the root directory, so you would use it like:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/my_javascript_file.js"></script>
```

Otherwise I think it could be a jQuery issue. Are you loading jQuery yourself? I recommend forcing Yii to load jQuery in the main layout (or whichever layout you are using for this view) like so:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```

I find this resolves most jQuery issues with Yii. Remove any references you may have put in to jQuery manually. Also, when loading an js file, it is recommended you use **registerScriptFile**:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/js/my_javascript_file.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/js/my_javascript_file.js', CClientScript::POS_READY); ?>
```

Depending on wheter you want it loaded in a ready block or in the head, use **POS_READY** or **POS_HEAD**

Hopefully this resolves your issues

Comment: Hmn, I thought I was using the base function. I've pasted in the script calls now. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Don't point to the assets directory, Yii auto adds the script to the assets.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out. I solved my problem, but as you say, I could do with reading around this a little more. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I've found where I was going wrong, or at least a work around.

I replaced-

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

With-

```
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/assets/js/jquery.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```